# SQL Query for Latest Input

Tags: sql

What is the query for the latest input in a database? `ASC` and `DESC` don't seem to work because I don't have a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the query for the latest input in a database.

By default there isn't.

Order isn't guaranteed in a relational database, it's specified by the `SELECT` query used to view the data.  If you want to order by "most recent" then you need a field which stores that information.  Something like a `DateAdded` field, for example.  (Which can either be populated by the application or just given a default value of the current date so it automatically adds the value on every `INSERT`.)  Then you'd simply order by that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable 
ORDER BY DateAdded DESC
```

> ASC and DESC don't seem to work

They do, you just need actual *values* by which to order the results of the query.

Answer (score -2):

Every table will have primary key. Use that key to get the latest entry.

SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Share your columns name. That might help to resolve your query.

Comment: The OP specifically states that he doesn't have a primary identifier on that table.

Comment: If there is no primary identifier in table then default pk would be id.

Comment: This is both incorrect and should not be an "answer."  It should be a comment.  If you don't have enough rep, develop some. (this is here on purpose).

Comment: @AvinashKrMallik: What database engine creates an `id` column when none is specified?  Not one I've ever used.  If there's no `id` column in the table schema then the database isn't going to add one automatically.  Observe: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e39f7/2

Comment: Sorry If I am wrong. But I have been working on Django, which is ORM based framework. If we do not add primary key in the model then it creates it's default pk i.e. id.
And as far as my knowledge is concerned, creating a database table without primary key is not a good way to model designing.
Correct me If I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @AvinashKrMallik: You are wrong.  First, this question makes no mention of Django, so why would you assume the OP is using that?  Second, there are valid reasons to create tables without primary keys and/or clustered indexes.  Just because the only framework you know how to use doesn't allow that functionality doesn't mean it's bad practice.

Comment: @David: I accept that it's not required to have a pk in every table. And also that db engine do not add default pk if not mentioned.
But I am just saying that it's always great to have your table indexed with pk. 

But, if we do not have pk in our table then auto datetime (If we have it, otherwise add it) column can be used to get the latest entry in the table,

Comment: @AvinashKrMallik: `But I am just saying that it's always great to have your table indexed with pk.` - You can say that all you like, but it's not correct.  Even if it were correct, there is *no* guarantee that the primary key will be the order of the data that the OP wants.  I can't stress this enough... There's a lot more to relational databases than your little framework has taught you.

Comment: @David: cool. no grudges. I will keep learning and try to expand my skill sets from little to enormous. Just be there on stackoverflow for your constant support. :-)

Comment: "*If there is no primary identifier in table then default pk would be id*" - that's plain wrong. There is no such thing as "default pk". And why would it be `id`?